# Failing to upload .snupkg file: The checksum does not match for the dll(s) and corresponding pdb(s)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, nuget, nuget-package

I have a C# WPF library on NuGet. After publishing a new release (.nupkg file), I wanted to also upload the Symbols package (.snupkg file). But I get `The checksum does not match for the dll(s) and corresponding pdb(s).` error:

[image: The error on NuGet]

I have successfully published .snupkg file together with .nupkg file for 2 other C# .NET Framework libraries, following the exact same procedure as here. The only difference that I can think of is that this a WPF library (it has *.xaml files and it has a reference to PresentationFramework), whereas the other two aren't.

---

The procedure:

1. The settings for Release configuration in the `.csproj` files:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\GM.WPF.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```

1. Rebuild *(this generates `.dll`, `.dll.config`, `.pdb`, `.xml` files in bin/Release)*.
2. I have a `.nuspec` file with the metadata for the NuGet package in the same folder as the `.csproj` file *(I don't think it's necessary to show the `.nuspec` file - not relevant to this problem)*.
3. Open PowerShell in this folder.
4. Execute command `nuget pack -Properties Configuration=Release -Symbols -SymbolPackageFormat snupkg` (this generates `.nupkg` and `.snupkg` files).
5. Upload `.nupkg` file to NuGet.
6. Upload `.snupkg` file to NuGet - **this is where I get the error**.

Please, if you need any other information, I can provide it.

Comment: Yay, I have the exact same problem. Curiously I am creating both in one routine, the .nupkg and the .snupkg. So its discrepancy is not plausible.

Comment: One workaround is to embed the pdb files in the nupkg file and drop snupkg support. It is not ideal, but some are suggesting this.

Comment: @Teroneko I am aware of this workaround, but I also realize that it is not ideal because the package is then bigger. I still want to know why this problem occurs.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well when trying to push symbols on AppVeyor - they are both generated based on the same build so I don't see how this can happen. Something weird is happening but I haven't figured it out yet

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this. I'm suddenly stumbling upon this issue. I've always been able to publish symbols in my github action, but for a new, specific project/package it always fails now...

Comment: @Pieterjan No, I haven't. For now, I'm doing the workaround that Teroneko mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

[Fody](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/InlineIL.Fody/issues/12)/Cecil - do not support checksums and cause that issue.

> [Currently, Cecil does not generate a PdbChecksum debug directory entry in the assembly it writes when it produces a portable PDB file.](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues/610)

Try to skip any post build steps that fiddle with your assembly or pdb before packing.